# Angular2: Declare Input Variable in Directive as required / not-required?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Can I declare a input var in a directive as required or even better as non-required? We have default value set to false here in example, but if I forget to declare in parent component template, then ng2 AoT says its an error:

```
 @Input() serverWaiting: boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Input are non-required as default. I don't think there is an option to make them required but you can do something like this:

```
@Input() serverWaiting: boolean = false; 
@Input() variableRequired: string; 
ngOnInit(){
    if(this.variableRequired==null){
       throw new Error('variableRequired field is required')
    }
}
```